# Problem to render sterescopic anaglyph

Tags: rendering

So, I have rendered anaglyphic images before but now when I try to do it the final image will not be cyan and red combined, it will just be two images from different angles, no cyan or red at all. I have it set to Stereo 3D, Anaglyph, red-cyan under Output and views format. I also have it set to Stereo 3D in "Views". I render the image and in the render view I see an image with red and cyan, but once I go F3 and save it as an image, then the final version, in the selected folder is two images with the R and L suffix (completely without red or cyan).

Anybody what this is all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are saving the image, in the save dialogue options, do you have by accident "Individual" checked instead of "Stereo 3D"?

[image]

Comment: Yes, man! That's it! Haha! Always the small things you miss while staring yourself blind at other things! :) Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @RickardAlexanderNilsson if this is a valid answer to your question, please mark it as answered here on StackExchange. You can also upvote it if you think it is helpful for others too. This will pay back some reputation points to AdamTM as a reward.